# Constructivity of zeros demanded by topological degree

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology

Let $f : S^{n - 1} \to S^{n - 1}$ be a smooth map from the unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to themselves. If $f$ has nonzero degree, then we know that any smooth map $g : D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ extending $f$ to the unit ball must take on the value $0$ at some point.

Given $g$, let us also define $h$ as the partial function $x \mapsto g(x)/\lvert g(x)\rvert$ with codomain $S^{n - 1}$, and consider the preimage of any of the regular values of $h$; these preimages will be $1$-manifolds, which can be "followed" from any starting points on $S^{n-1}$ till either: (A) terminating at another point on $S^{n - 1}$, or (B) approaching a zero of $g$.

In the particular case where $f$ is the identity, we can rule out possibility (A), and conclude (with help from Sard's theorem) that for almost all starting points on $S^{n - 1}$, one can follow such paths to zeros of $g$. (This is, as I understand it, essentially the Kellog/Hirsch-style proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem)

But what of cases where $\deg(f) > 1$? Here, at least naively we must worry about the possibility that every such path starting on the sphere will only end up terminating at a suitable other point on the sphere. Is there in this context still any reason to hope to be able to find zeros of $g$ along these lines (pun sort of intended)?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly,  some of these paths may connect a couple of points $a$ and $b$ on the same fiber of $f$, $f(a)=f(b)=c\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$,  but  at one of them $f$ preserves the orientation, and exchanges it at the other, so that $Df_a:T_a\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\to T_c\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and $Df_b:T_b\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\to T_c\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ together do not contribute to the degree of $f$. So we can conclude that  at least $|\mathrm{deg}(f)|$ of these paths actually bring to a zero of $g$; only we can't tell locally which paths are the good ones.

Comment: Ah, this is nice. Still, I wonder if there might be some way to push further! (It irks me that there should be such a nice zero-finding algorithm for the degree 1 case and not others). Does there actually exist, for example, so "pathological" a case as that only finitely many surface starting points work out?

Comment: In fact I 'm not sure I understand how this algorithm works. Case (A) may occur for a degree $1$ map, right?

Comment: If $f$ is of degree 1, it is homotopic to the identity; thus, we can "augment" $g$ so that it is defined on a slightly larger ball than originally, on whose surface it now acts as the identity. And then, considering this augmented $g$, case (A) cannot occur, since surface points are all mapped to different directions.